# Are Parse::Yapp, Parse::Lex or Marpa::R2 still used?

Tags: perl, parsing

I would like to write simple parser in Perl that mainly provide an additional layer over an existing language. I was looking at `Parse::Yapp`, `Parse::Lex` or even `Marpa::R2`, but the only concrete example is always the same: a simple calculator that does `43 * 8 + 1`. I cannot easily find any other examples so I am wondering if these packages are still a good choice to implement a parser.

Are `Parse::Yapp`, `Parse::Lex` or `Marpa::R2` still a good solution over a [hand-rolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476116/yaml-parsing-lex-or-hand-rolled) approach?

Where can I find more examples and documentation on these modules? The CPAN pages are usually pretty empty

Comment: Check the links [here](https://github.com/choroba/marpa-enhanced-calculator) for non-calculator examples on [Marpa::R2](http://p3rl.org/Marpa::R2)
.

Comment: Try something like `calc.pl 'a = 43 b = 3 * 8; print a + b'`. But the point was to show the other links :-)

Comment: I updated the code in GitHub to accept input without a trailing separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For small simple parser jobs like this sort of thing, I wrote [`Parser::MGC`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Parser::MGC). Your particular case of numerical expression evaluation is likely some variant of one of the examples, namely

https://metacpan.org/source/PEVANS/Parser-MGC-0.13/examples/eval-expr.pl

Comment: imho the op want much more as simple numerical expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Marpa::R2 is in heavy and increasing use.  IBM advertises their use of it: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jalvord/entry/sitworld_itm_situation_audit?lang=en  Metacpan lists ~30 direct dependences and there are indirect dependences from those.  There are open-source C, ECMAScript parsers.  There's more stuff listed on the web site: http://savage.net.au/Marpa.html#Applications

Comment: From this [study](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2012/3513/pdf/6.pdf) Marpa looks pretty inefficient

Comment: Note the date; that it is talking about an earlier version of Marpa, Marpa::XS; and the methodological caveats.  Alberto was gracious enough to share his paper with me before publication and it inspired a lot of the changes which appeared in Marpa::R2.